# Why do I get this NullReferenceException sometimes?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

Here's piece of code where It throws the exception sometimes:

```
Pendings = ClientCode.PendingOrders.Select(x => new DisplayPending()
{
    ItemCode = ClientCode.Items.First(y => y.Id == x.ItemCode).Id,
    ItemName = ClientCode.Items.First(y => y.Id == x.ItemCode).Name,
    OrderNo = x.BuyOrderNo == 0 ? x.SellOrderNo : x.BuyOrderNo,
    OrderType = x.OrderType == OrderType.Buy ? "Buy" : "Sell",
    PartyCode = x.PartyCode,
    Price = x.Price,
    Quantity = x.Quantity
});
```

and here's the message:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

x was null.
```

`PendingOrders` is an`ObservableCollection` and It has more than 500 items.

**EDIT**

Here's how I populate my extended `ObservableCollection`:

```
public class AsyncObsetion<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    SynchronizationContext context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    readonly object _lock = new object();
    public AsyncObsetion() { BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _lock); }
    public AsyncObsetion(IEnumerable<T> list) : base(list) { BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _lock); }

    void RaiseCollectionChanged(object param) => base.OnCollectionChanged((NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)param);
    void RaisePropertyChanged(object param) => base.OnPropertyChanged((PropertyChangedEventArgs)param);

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == context) RaiseCollectionChanged(e);
        else context.Send(RaiseCollectionChanged, e);
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == context) RaisePropertyChanged(e);
        else context.Send(RaisePropertyChanged, e);
    }

    public void InsertRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this.CheckReentrancy();
        foreach (var item in items)
            this.Items.Add(item);
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

When `Client` connects to `Server`, it sends 6 `byte[]` which are added in 8 `AsyncObsetion<T>` named `Items`, `NewsCollection`, `Issued`, `BuyOrders`, `SellOrders`, `PendingOrders`, `ExecutedOrders` and `MyExecutedOrders` on client side. This piece of code is responible for handling those `byte[]` which client gets from server:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < header.ItemSize; i += Constants.itemSize)
    {
        var item = PacMan<ItemStruct>.Unpack(itemArray.Skip(i).Take(Constants.itemSize).ToArray());
        Items.Add(new Item()
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Name = item.Name,
            Cap = item.Cap,
            Floor = item.Floor,
            Mid = item.Floor + ((item.Cap - item.Floor) / 2),
            Securities = item.Securities,
            Owners = item.Owners,
            Govt = item.Govt,
            Institutions = item.Institutions,
            Foreign = item.Foreign,
            Public = item.Public,
            PerSecurity = PacMan<PerSecurityFinancialsStruct>.ArrayToList<PerSecurityFinancials>(item.PerSecurity),
            Dividends = PacMan<DividendStruct>.ArrayToList<Dividend>(item.Dividends),
            InitialSecurity = item.InitialSecurity
        });
    }
}).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (header.HasExecuted) GetExOrders(header.ExecutedSize, execArray);
    if (header.HasNews) AddNews(newsArray.ToArray());
}));

tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => { if (header.HasBuy) GetOrders(header.BuySize, buyArray, "buy"); }));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => { if (header.HasSell) GetOrders(header.SellSize, sellArray, "sell"); }));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => AddIssue(issueArray.ToArray())));
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

hasReceivedData = true;
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested());
OnConnected();
OrderVM.ItemCode = Items.First().Id;


e.Completed += Receive;
e.SetBuffer(headerBuffer, 0, headerBuffer.Length);
if (!e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(e)) Receive(null, e);
```

`OnConnected()` is an event and when it's fired client starts the process of creating `Pendings` out of `PendingOrders`, which is made out of `buyArray` and `sellArray`. I think here's the problem and I believe somehow `OnConnected()` gets fired before `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray())` sometimes. If someone is interested, here's what `GetOrders` does:

```
void GetOrders(int size, IEnumerable<byte> array, string type)
{
    var orderList = new List<AllOrder>();
    var pendingList = new List<AllOrder>();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += Constants.orderSize)
    {
        var order = PacMan<AllOrderStruct>.Unpack(array.Skip(i).Take(Constants.orderSize).ToArray());
        AddInitNewOrder(order, orderList, pendingList);
    }
    if (type == "buy") CheckNumberAndAdd(orderList, BuyOrders);
    else CheckNumberAndAdd(orderList, SellOrders);
    CheckNumberAndAdd(pendingList, PendingOrders);
}
```

here's `AddInitNewOrder`:

```
void AddInitNewOrder(AllOrderStruct order, List<AllOrder> orders, List<AllOrder> pendingOrders)
{
    var o = new AllOrder();
    o.Action = order.Action;
    o.OrderType = order.OrderType;
    o.ItemCode = order.ItemCode;
    o.BrokerName = order.BrokerName;
    o.PartyCode = order.PartyCode;
    o.Price = order.Price;
    o.Quantity = order.Quantity;
    o.BuyOrderNo = order.BuyOrderNo;
    o.SellOrderNo = order.SellOrderNo;
    orders.Add(o);
    if (o.BrokerName == BrokerName) pendingOrders.Add(o);
}
```

and here's `CheckNumberAndAdd`:

```
void CheckNumberAndAdd<T>(List<T> normList, AsyncObsetion<T> obsList)
{
    var count = normList.Count;
    if(count > 50)
    {
        obsList.InsertRange(normList.Take(count - 50));
        var remaining = normList.Skip(count - 50).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < remaining.Count; i++) obsList.Insert(0, remaining[i]);                
    }
    else for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) obsList.Insert(0, normList[i]);                         
}
```

If I set brekpoint in `GetOrders` function, I see `pendingList` gets 483 items from `sellArray` and 494 items from `buyArray`, so altogether I've 977 items. So I should get 977 Items in `PendingOrders` always BUT If I remove brekpoint in `GetOrders` and set breakpoint in `Subscribe` method, which is hooked into that event `ClientCode.OnConnected += Subscribe;` I see `PendingOrders` sometimes gets less than 977 items.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: you'r using `.First` keyword. If Id and itemcode not matched means, it gives error. Use `.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == x.ItemCode)` and try

Comment: @sriharsha, it has matching items.

Comment: @sriharsha .First will throw ArgumentNullException, not NullReferenceException

Comment: @EmonHaque, Can you show the model of `DisplayPending`. Also, can you show sample values of `ClientCode.PendingOrders` and `ClientCode.Items`

Comment: What is the problem? Error message is quite verbose. It reads: _"... x was null"_. And `x` is referencing an item of the `PendingOrders` collection. Just make sure that all items are initialized and that you don't add `null` to the collection. Before you add an item to the collection check for `null` before you add items to the collection. `if (item != null) PendingOrders.Add(item)`.

Comment: @BionicCode, `PendingOrders` has more than 500 items in it!

Comment: So what? You where adding them at one point to the collection. Just add a `null` check:  `if (item != null) PendingOrders.Add(item)`.

Comment: Alternatively use LINQ: `ClientCode.PendingOrders.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => ...)`

Comment: Null Coalescing Operator in C# in the fastest way to handle nullable type in LINQ.

Comment: @XAMT It's noit faster. It's just syntactic sugar to improve readability. It's a simple comparison with `null` under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

As @BionicCode stated, you just have some null elements in the collection.

Just filter them out with `.Where(x != null)` or similar.
Although this might solve the problem, generally undetected null references are a hint about week points in the code.

Consider reinforcing your null check policy to avoid these errors in the future. The same framework allows you to perform checks on nullable objects, making the code cleaner and more robust.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/february/essential-net-csharp-8-0-and-nullable-reference-types

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve the issue is to wrap the last three lines of `GetOrders` method like this:

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    if (type == "buy") CheckNumberAndAdd(orderList, BuyOrders);
    else CheckNumberAndAdd(orderList, SellOrders);
    CheckNumberAndAdd(pendingList, PendingOrders);
});
```

this works.